# Light box image automatically change to the next image

Tags: lightbox2

Is there a way to get lightbox to automatically move on to the next image without the need for pressing the arrow buttons to move on?

The view I'm asking about is when one has already clicked on the already moving carousel to get the lightbox(Image attached below).

View of lightbox I want to automatically move to the next image.

[image: Screen Shot]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Lightbox API doesn't expose this feature but you can programmatically click on the 'next' navigation button with Javascript. This could be done on a timer with `setInterval`.

```
// Simplified code
setInterval(() => {
    $('.lb-next').trigger('click');
}, 2000)
```